# how to resolve promise chain in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Iam using jQuery and get object of 4 `promises` in response, now how to get the resolves value of each promise? in angular i can use `$q.all()`and on `.then()` it will resolve all values; but that does not work in jQuery .then. below are the code snippet

```
var _service = function() {};
var ec2;

_service.prototype = {

    init: function(formdata, cb) {
        console.info('::init::', arguments[0]);           
        ec2 = new AWS.EC2(ec2_config);
        return ec2.promise();
    },
    loop: function(param) {
        console.info('createAdditionalResources params:', arguments);
        return $.when({
            'fun1': this.fun1(param),
            'fun2': this.fun2(param),
            'fun3': this.fun3(param),
            'fun4': this.fun4(param)       
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log('Done All');
            return response;
        });
    },
    fun1: function (param) {
        return something.promise(); //  return promise
    },
    ....
 };

window.obj = new _service();
```

here I call this function in my script

```
function foo() {
 var d = $.Deferred();

obj.init()
.then(function(res) {
    return obj.loop();
})
.then(function(res) {
    console.log(res); // this is promise chain
    d.resolve(res);
})
.catch(function(err) {
   d.reject(err);
});
return d.promise();
};
```

here *res* comes with this `{fun1: Promise, fun2: Promise, fun3:Promise, fun4:Promise }`

and fun1  has below value

```
fun1: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: { InternetGateway: { Attachments:[{InternetGatewayId:"igw-6253970b"}] }
```

now how to resolve value?

Comment: yes you are right; in 1st snippet , i just add in case we need? I am asking ehether we need it or not? in second snippet; I am using `d.resolve(response)` in last **then** block and `d.reject` in **catch** block and than `return d.promise()` .let me update the 2nd snippet

Comment: Given that (at least in `fun1`) you are using native promises anyway, why not simply go for `Promise.all`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you pass to `$.when` isn't a promise, nor promises, it's handled just as if it was a basic value: it's given as resolution.

Here's a way to wait for the resolution of several promises:

```
    return $.when(
        this.fun1(),
        this.fun2(),
        this.fun3(),
        this.fun4()       
    ).done(function(fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4) {
        console.log('Done All');
        return {fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4};
    });
```

You can also write a small utility to have all object properties solved:

```
function solveProps(obj){
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        return $.when.apply($, keys.map(k=>obj[k])).done(function(){
                var     solved = {};
                for (var i=0k i<keys.length; i++) {
                        solved[keys[i]] = arguments[i];
                }
                return solved;
        });
}
```

With this utility you would just have

```
    return solveProps({
            fun1: this.fun1(),
            fun2: this.fun2(),
            fun3: this.fun3(),
            fun4: this.fun4()
    });
```

Comment: can i use key value on this function? like `fun1 : this.fun1`  as i am getting all 4 response  in promise

Comment: You can also make an utility to have all properties of an object solved as promises if you want. Do you need me to write it ?

Comment: this has same response. no changes; also using `return {x,y,z}` giving error with jshint ( only allowed in es6)

Comment: The `return {x,y,z}` thing assumes you're using ES6 and have your linter properly configured. If you can't, just do `return {x:x,y:y,z:z}`

Comment: is there no such ways to resolve via jquery Deferred method?